# How to index date values into columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, power-query

I have the following table in Excel 2016:

```
ID  Type1            Type2            Type3  
1   01.03.2018       null             01.02.2019
2   01.04.2018       01.05.2018       null
3   null             01.03.2018       01.05.2018
```

Now I am trying to index those values into a new table which should look like the following:

```
ID  01.02.2018       01.03.2018       01.04.2018    01.05.2018     
1   Type3            Type1            null          null
2   null             null             Type1         Type2
3   null             Type2            null          Type3
```

What is the best way to achieve that? Using Power Query or with Excel functions? And how can I achieve that transformation?

Comment: What does you want to obtain when 2 different `TypeN` have the same date for different `ID`?

Comment: @Akina Duplication is possible. I just want to change the view, group the types by the dates by transforming the date to columns.

Comment: *Duplication is possible.* And? does you want to obtain something like `Type5,Type8` in a cell with according  row (ID value) and column (date value)?

Comment: I want to achieve exactly what you see in table 2.
For each ID there should be visible which types are occuring in which date. I want to transform table 1 to table 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this all in Power Query

- Select the `ID` column and `Unpivot other columns`
- Optionally `Sort` the rows in the `Value` column
- Pivot on the `Value` column, with the Values column set to `Attribute` and the Advanced options select `Don't Aggregate`

[image]

That's it!

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Type1", type date}, {"Type2", type date}, {"Type3", type date}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Value", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Value", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Value", type text}}, "en-US")[Value]), "Value", "Attribute")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

**Source Data**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

***Null*** is a reserved word in M, so if you need to show the actual word "null", you need to replace `null` with something that makes it a string. You could use something like `#(00A0)null` which prefixes the null with the NBSP, or `#(200B)null` which is ZWSP (zero-width space).  And there may be other tricks you can use.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this requirement with a mix of Power Query and Power Pivot (Excel Data Model).

First I would build a Power Query. Select the ID column and use the Unpivot Other Columns feature to transform the data into **Attribute** (input column name e.g. Type1) and **Value** (input cell value e.g. 01.02.2018).  I would set the query to load into the Data Model (Power Pivot).

Then I would create a Pivot Table based on the Data Model, using the **Value** column for the Rows and the **Attribute** column for the cells.

You can rename those generated columns to suit. I prefer to do this in Power Query for better transparency.

Comment: Sound good! I did the step with Power Query and opened the data model in Power Pivot but never used Power Pivot before. How can I set the Value column for the rows and Attribute column for cells?

Comment: Mmmm Mangos ... From the Insert ribbon choose Pivot Table, then for "Choose the data ..." select "Use this workbook's Data Model".